# UITableview Update Single Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I got a play button on my `tableview` custom cell, whenever I tapped the play button. I want the selected button image to change to pause image.

The issue is that all the other buttons images are getting updated.

So all the images are changing to the pause image, instead of the selected button.

I tried to get the `indexpath` of the button tapped and reload only that row, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let playerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
        let item = subcategory?.items?[indexPath.row]
        // Tap gestures extension for cell button action
        playerCell.playPause.addTapGestureRecognizer {
            AudioController.shared.setupPlayer(item: item)
            if let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
                selectedCell.playPause.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause"), for: .normal)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 1)], with: .none)
            }
            print("index \(indexPath)")
        }
```

Comment: is it after you scrolled?

Comment: no, as soon as I tapped the play button all the buttons changed to pause image.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add a tag to the button. So within the method that you create the cells `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, you add a tag to the button within that cells that represents the indexPath. Then from within the selector that you assign the button, you can get the cell that you want to alter.

For example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.button.tag = indePath.row
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourSelector(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
} 

func yourSelector(_sender: UIButton){
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as! YourCellType

    // Change the image, play/pause audio for that cell
}
```

Comment: thank for your response, but whenever I tapped the button. The didSelectRowAt indexpath is not getting called. because I am not actually tapping the row

Comment: @IamWayne Ah I see. Are you using your own custom `UITableViewCell` type? Or are you using static cells that you defined in the storyboard?

Comment: I am using a custom cell, not static cell.

Comment: @IamWayne What you can do is add a tag to the button. So within the method that you create the cells ( `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` ), you add a tag to the button within that cells that represents the indexPath. Then from within the selector that you assign the button, you can get the cell that you want to alter. I'll edit my answer so that it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on the button in cell, `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` won't be trigger, so I suggest using `delegate` to detect button action.

And you need to keep tracking the change of the cell's button status.

---

#### For example:

PlayCell.swift

```
protocol PlayCellDelegate: class {
    func playCellPlayButtonDidPress(at indexPath: IndexPath)
}    
class PlayerCell: UITableViewCell {
    let playButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    weak var delegate: PlayCellDelegate?
    var item: MyItem? {
        didSet {
            if item?.status == .paused {
                // set pause image for playButton here
            } else if item?.status == .playing {
                // set play image for playButton here
            }
        }
    }
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    @objc func playButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let indexPath = self.indexPath else { return }
        delegate?.playCellPlayButtonDidPress(at: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Model.swift

```
struct Subcategory {
    // ...
    var items: [MyItem]?
}
struct MyItem {
    // ...
    var status: Status.stop
    enum Status {
        case playing, paused, stopped // etc..
    }
}
```

TableViewController.swift

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, PlayCellDelegate {
    private var subcategory: Subcategory?
    private let cellId = "Cell"        
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.item = subcategory?.items?[indexPath.row]
            cell.indexPath = indexPath
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func playCellPlayButtonDidPress(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // you only need to change model here, and reloadRows will update the cell.
        if subcategory?.items?[indexPath.row].status == .play {
            subcategory?.items?[indexPath.row].status = .pause
        } // other logic..
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your response. The button action is working and it is triggered fine. The issue is the button state inside the cell. I am trying to change only the selected button image and not the button image for all the cells. I am new to swift programming and I don't much if anything about protocols yet.

Comment: So question is **'You want to change the image of play button from play to pause?'**

Comment: Yes, the button is changing but it's changing on all the cells. I just want to change it for the slected row button...